# Rails render Xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

In my Rails app,I run the follow action:

```
def test  
    data={:student=>{:name=>'hxh',:age=>12}}
    render xml: data 
end
```

I got

```
<hash slick-uniqueid="3">
  <div>
    <a id="slick_uniqueid"/>
  </div>
  <student>
    <name>hxh</name>
    <age type="integer">12</age>
  </student>
</hash>
```

But I just want:

```
<student>
    <name>hxh</name>
    <age type="integer">12</age>
 </student>
```

How I should realize this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a few minutes of playing around in the console I can give you this solution:

Set your hash to this:

```
data = {:name=>'hxh',:age=>12}
```

Now you can use the :root option to specify your root:

```
data.to_xml(root: "student")
```

This will yield the following result:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<student>
    <name>hxh</name>
    <age type=\"integer\">12</age>
</student>
```

You can also add this option `:skip_instruct => true` to get rid of the first line.

Also do read up on the [documentation here](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/to_xml).